# Jquery - MVC - Functionname is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I searched this error and tried other people`s solution but it does not fixed.I changed jquery  versions , write code from beginning vs vs but still same.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetID(int ID)
    {
        List<User> users = db.users.ToList();
        User user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ID);
        return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



 <button onclick="dataget()" id="personID" style="margin-left: 28%;"> <span class="fa fa-arrow-left text-dark" style="font-size:30px" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataget = function () {
        var ID = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Finder/GetID/' + ID,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Name").html(data.Name);
                $("#Surname").html(data.Surname);
            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Is this inside a form? Perhaps you want `<button type="button"`

Comment: it is still same

Comment: Where did you define your script? is it on a separate file?

Comment: No, bottom of the html

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir i added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your button;

```
<button id="personID" style="margin-left: 28%;">
   ...
</button>
```

You need to put your script inside a razor section, it will be inserted to script section in your layout.

```
@section script {
   <script type="text/javascript">

      // execute this function upon page ready
      $(document).ready(function(){

         // bind the event to your button
         $("#personID").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            
            //Fetch form data
            var sendData = { ID:1 };

            $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("Find","GetID")',
               type: 'POST',
               data: sendData,
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               success: function (data) {
                  $("#Name").html(data.Name);
                  $("#Surname").html(data.Surname);
               }
            });
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I tried but still same ,doesn`t working.

Comment: still same.I think i give up soon

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir that's odd. Will you include the full view code. And your layout as well.

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir updated the code, you need to remove the onclick in your button because we are already binding the event in the script.

Comment: Error gone but i have a new problem, it does not call the method in controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242879/discussion-between-muhammet-ugur-bozdemir-and-jerdine-sabio).

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir I updated the script, since you are using datatype:json, you need to format your data like json

Comment: Still same,what could I be overlooking?

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir try updating sendData to `var sendData = { ID:1 };`

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir Also add a breakpoint to your controller action.

Comment: I add breakpoint,code does not reach breakpoint.

Comment: @MuhammetUgurBozdemir let's use url helper for the url and add content type. `@Url.Action("Find","GetID")`. I updated the script

Comment: still not working, i gave up my friend thank you so much for your help.I`ll try find another way,

Comment: I used his code to reach working code that is why ı accept